# NodeJs fails to send email with gmail smtp

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

After reading some posts, I don't know why this meteor code fails to send the email to my own email address. Any idea is most appreciated.

```js
//server.main.js

import { Email } from 'meteor/email'

smtp = {
  username: 'my@gmail.com',
  password: 'pass',
  server: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: '465'
};

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;

//then inside a method call
Testimonies.insert(testamonyObj, function(err, res) {
      if (!err) {
        let add = 'myAdd@gmail.com'
        let mess = 'alosh bel awee'
        Email.send({ add, add, res, mess });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the options object you are passing to `Email.send` just doesn't contain the necessary fields, most notably the `to` field, see
https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html#Email-send. Your current objects contains only three fields `add`, `res`, and `mess`, none of which are valid field names understood by the `send` function.

Try this:

```
Email.send({ 
  to: add,
  from: add,
  subject: res,
  text: mess
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine from the first glance. You need to allow less secure applications in your gmail account.

You can read more about it here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Yes. I had to do this step which allowed me to fix after I used the accepted answer. thx